# 中間CA証明書が正常にインストールされているかをopensslコマンドで確認する方法

Tags: ssl, openssl

[こちらの解説](https://jp.globalsign.com/support/faq/58.html)によると中間CA証明書がインストールされていない場合にPC上のブラウザでは補完を行うが携帯端末では情報の保管を行わないためにSSLのエラーになってしまう事があるそうなのですが、

`openssl`コマンドで状況を確認するときに出力のどこを見ればいつ期限が切れたかがわかるのでしょうか？

[globalsign-のルート証明書の件について](https://nakacya.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/globalsign-%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E8%A8%BC%E6%98%8E%E6%9B%B8%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%B6%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/) という記事を参考に

```
$ wget https://jp.globalsign.com/
--2015-02-12 20:41:25--  https://jp.globalsign.com/
Resolving jp.globalsign.com... 198.41.214.156, 198.41.215.156
Connecting to jp.globalsign.com|198.41.214.156|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify jp.globalsign.com's certificate, issued by `/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G2':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to jp.globalsign.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

して`wget`だとエラーが出ることは確認しました。

それと`$ openssl s_client -connect jp.globalsign.com:443 -showcerts` コマンドで以下の出力になることを確認していますが、期限切れについての情報は自分には見つけられませんでした。

```
$ openssl s_client -connect jp.globalsign.com:443 -showcerts                                                                          
CONNECTED(00000003)                                                                                                                   
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G2                                            
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate                                                                            
verify return:0                                                                                                                       
---                                                                                                                                   
Certificate chain                                                                                                                     
 0 s:/businessCategory=Private Organization/serialNumber=0110-01-040181/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=JP/C=JP/ST=Tokyo/L=Shibuya/street=26-
1 Sakuragaoka/O=GMO GlobalSign K.K./CN=jp.globalsign.com                                                                              
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G2                                                      
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----                                                                                                           
MIIHkDCCBnigAwIBAgIMeE3tF6LAhw5MF6WZMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMGIxCzAJ                                                                      
BgNVBAYTAkJFMRkwFwYDVQQKExBHbG9iYWxTaWduIG52LXNhMTgwNgYDVQQDEy9H                                                                      
bG9iYWxTaWduIEV4dGVuZGVkIFZhbGlkYXRpb24gQ0EgLSBTSEEyNTYgLSBHMjAe                                                                      
Fw0xNTAxMjMwMjMxMDNaFw0xNzAxMjMwMjMxMDNaMIHRMR0wGwYDVQQPDBRQcml2                                                                      
YXRlIE9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbjEXMBUGA1UEBRMOMDExMC0wMS0wNDAxODExEzARBgsr                                                                      
BgEEAYI3PAIBAxMCSlAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkpQMQ4wDAYDVQQIEwVUb2t5bzEQMA4G                                                                      
A1UEBxMHU2hpYnV5YTEZMBcGA1UECRMQMjYtMSBTYWt1cmFnYW9rYTEcMBoGA1UE                                                                      
ChMTR01PIEdsb2JhbFNpZ24gSy5LLjEaMBgGA1UEAxMRanAuZ2xvYmFsc2lnbi5j                                                                      
b20wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDCrr8ESC0H8erg51T3                                                                      
O666u0oJe6E1fx6slXawZTHFcnOjYa1csEZj4hr2WAqQv2HLkgwjOejg1xeN1/GJ                                                                      
S5J/1gX8PiAAqwwR5DkUXCDMgeS8B9iOvYfnieaM0au/ohyMFyPa//SRmMFwBzOe                                                                      
9EoQ6ToYRKXDLwo7JAWrIl+lgj+QZxUWCu1xax4B9Dktv0DEsXkgSSNwfbzG66gI                                                                      
OqMoPjSxliGYoEHjhBD9BAT7veHro1fcB689jZpZy5qEJYm1C/we1WU1NlCIgZW3                                                                      
r5qYj9vTHFpGR233dUhbStyuagBBwA6clEvz5WNwDkLcvTPQ8urQADfhIin/9hxD                                                                      
1FRFAgMBAAGjggPUMIID0DAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBaAwTAYDVR0gBEUwQzBBBgkr                                                                      
BgEEAaAyAQEwNDAyBggrBgEFBQcCARYmaHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ2xvYmFsc2lnbi5j                                                                      
b20vcmVwb3NpdG9yeS8wQwYDVR0fBDwwOjA4oDagNIYyaHR0cDovL2NybC5nbG9i                                                                      
YWxzaWduLmNvbS9ncy9nc2V4dGVuZHZhbHNoYTJnMi5jcmwwgZQGCCsGAQUFBwEB                                                                      
BIGHMIGEMEcGCCsGAQUFBzAChjtodHRwOi8vc2VjdXJlLmdsb2JhbHNpZ24uY29t                                                                      
L2NhY2VydC9nc2V4dGVuZHZhbHNoYTJnMnIyLmNydDA5BggrBgEFBQcwAYYtaHR0                                                                      
cDovL29jc3AyLmdsb2JhbHNpZ24uY29tL2dzZXh0ZW5kdmFsc2hhMmcyMB0GA1Ud                                                                      
JQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMBBggrBgEFBQcDAjAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMDMGA1UdEQQsMCqC                                                                      
EWpwLmdsb2JhbHNpZ24uY29tghVlLXNpZ24uZ2xvYmFsc2lnbi5jb20wHQYDVR0O                                                                      
BBYEFM+wSVoWN0GnoGFZhl47qY3fz+OBMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFNpAd0NlHPj+p+P0                                                                      
ZII+TUMTIjECMIIB8wYKKwYBBAHWeQIEAgSCAeMEggHfAd0AdQBo9pj4H2SCvjqM                                                                      
7rkoHUz8cVFdZ5PURNEKZ6y7T0/7xAAAAUsUoOiGAAAEAwBGMEQCIFDpbMPCSZVT                                                                      
+TVT/giIldH9jZC9O+EN7Ue7q3cav1o9AiAnJZH+KBLBeFXLcfpYHlyhct6k192I                                                                      
oIjggp71t3hQXgB1AKS5CZC0GFgUh7sTosxncAo8NZgE+RvfuON3zQ7IDdwQAAAB                                                                      
SxSg79sAAAQDAEYwRAIgDkBLdLtOQVwLubMkMNU1F8FRa/ys8V5W8EKZpfTsRZ0C                                                                      
IFqsdtOH+XL2+wY3iCgS5ARIMGcL9sxHhZfWLhqfU28cAHUA7ku9t3XOYLrhQmkf                                                                      
q+GeZqMPfl+wctiDAMR7iXqo/csAAAFLFKD+DAAABAMARjBEAiBUNPJJ9qjkTvVa                                                                      
5g8aXJwS+MhkE10lpd47eorB9TKBuwIgcY7BfTSEZvbJbOGGqWxITPRTId8nuI3w                                                                      
BNyvk8NiPLEAdgBWFAaaL9fC7NP14b1Esj7HRna5vJkRXMDvlJhV1onQ3QAAAUsU                                                                      
oQKLAAAEAwBHMEUCIQCG9KCaQxQVBDSdrHCEXLXifPiE8hiRiQ08uWgeDOEGpAIg                                                                      
Enwvy003ocbQBvV78SVpJYF4BGIejuazVKvbP9mBuH4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAD                                                                      
ggEBAFjN1+MRRIVwq7pmj9ErQ5D305QpXaokvlxZ4wGlw1gNvWLbH6Jj1vXlLoFu                                                                      
JqCUxKvQUmzoZKWRMkKX/yjKiFvw8Cb4abr4XT7DfbjHnJryH1M63lgKsattN6BH                                                                      
kTp/0jiYF/Q7oYWBH0zQ0KQLfGWzupUf8Y1gnxgTduukKky9J3s9Vxe5+Dl3QPwV                                                                      
1YTuLK8UHFGrxQSnYNzsnrYF3q3cSYiBHAeUzMFI8fYULWoHdzXoN78xi3AxH8Nj                                                                      
kexuSwZGnUCtLOJ0OoTQg2TRFmkBSJCNHCxwWnOWdwQ6krT0znrGcon0oPhTpyG5                                                                      
sZTsvwFeDcFq9xCAtWhBPRkz+ec=                                                                                                          
-----END CERTIFICATE-----                                                                                                             
 1 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G2                                                      
   i:/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign                                                                           
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----                                                                                                           
MIIEXTCCA0WgAwIBAgILBAAAAAABRE7wSlUwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwTDEgMB4G                                                                      
A1UECxMXR2xvYmFsU2lnbiBSb290IENBIC0gUjIxEzARBgNVBAoTCkdsb2JhbFNp                                                                      
Z24xEzARBgNVBAMTCkdsb2JhbFNpZ24wHhcNMTQwMjIwMTAwMDAwWhcNMjExMjE1                                                                      
MDgwMDAwWjBiMQswCQYDVQQGEwJCRTEZMBcGA1UEChMQR2xvYmFsU2lnbiBudi1z                                                                      
YTE4MDYGA1UEAxMvR2xvYmFsU2lnbiBFeHRlbmRlZCBWYWxpZGF0aW9uIENBIC0g                                                                      
U0hBMjU2IC0gRzIwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCj6qHS                                                                      
w0nl9xxdr8OSQq+KPNzvTOYvXwwrn4pQMGbvTshPIUr25/JOG4xTV7CeyFv3uEZV                                                                      
sxrtwmr+9BvsSEYOj+D74JEZ35kYby5Rr9r2mspkb5lUEHTqPMiqgE1DN/vIpH8F                                                                      
nTeSvZgANVqvu1t0FQ68vMbpt4bn7q5NSwRMK6C0ZUi4wzrNdbs3yUrAARHZvz8V                                                                      
hmAZazQgRvWGZg8k9Mxin5+eHf0QpJle8EHrsJT/LLM21usdpxdf385qd8eaxDJj                                                                      
pwat8xIbnTByWQvrcusq0nd7kXfbAPzYb/Uv2HrFDDqge16Q852EWcgB2ZE3VuU6                                                                      
U5OtYEknJdnh2oLXAgMBAAGjggEoMIIBJDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwEgYDVR0T                                                                      
AQH/BAgwBgEB/wIBADAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU2kB3Q2Uc+P6n4/Rkgj5NQxMiMQIwRwYD                                                                      
VR0gBEAwPjA8BgRVHSAAMDQwMgYIKwYBBQUHAgEWJmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmdsb2Jh                                                                      
bHNpZ24uY29tL3JlcG9zaXRvcnkvMDYGA1UdHwQvMC0wK6ApoCeGJWh0dHA6Ly9j                                                                      
cmwuZ2xvYmFsc2lnbi5uZXQvcm9vdC1yMi5jcmwwPQYIKwYBBQUHAQEEMTAvMC0G                                                                      
CCsGAQUFBzABhiFodHRwOi8vb2NzcC5nbG9iYWxzaWduLmNvbS9yb290cjIwHwYD                                                                      
VR0jBBgwFoAUm+IHV2ccHsBqBt5ZtJot39wZhi4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEB                                                                      
AEDvEpCDdJaK+Tq6m1lKM9PvTBMrtZHLyZbtbvVsZPHGhLJGWVpYglLxNKBUQWQg                                                                      
q9hXO9QUdHEYNswTwcdwwPVFZg5xroevkpTrcUAJ9Mx39xuThYpKrjOF5nSu9RCm                                                                      
PslZg8P5XJb5KPc0e+k4xpE8T3FYdf7hVnV2zUDEFUA5qUH9ZBAPl4UH6Hlk0FtN                                                                      
TJsnl9NzXpJ+H0jiyrkFl07vLBxrTYpfeFOVzQI5wi/maU/2cdGZtX9tIN5Dj9sA                                                                      
G6M7N97RP23ztpB2Haydb4RPJJQJduCdqE33TTePpC9fS0HkSRaXzHtsrxHKllQJ                                                                      
iyRRrl3tovG7UxBNl/oadwM=                                                                                                              
-----END CERTIFICATE-----                                                                                                             
---                                                                                                                                   
Server certificate                                                                                                                    
subject=/businessCategory=Private Organization/serialNumber=0110-01-040181/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=JP/C=JP/ST=Tokyo/L=Shibuya/street=
26-1 Sakuragaoka/O=GMO GlobalSign K.K./CN=jp.globalsign.com                                                                           
issuer=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Extended Validation CA - SHA256 - G2                                                    
---                                                                                                                                   
No client certificate CA names sent                                                                                                   
---                                                                                                                                   
SSL handshake has read 3718 bytes and written 432 bytes                                                                               
---                                                                                                                                   
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256                                                                               
Server public key is 2048 bit                                                                                                         
Secure Renegotiation IS supported                                                                                                     
Compression: NONE                                                                                                                     
Expansion: NONE                                                                                                                       
SSL-Session:                                                                                                                          
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2                                                                                                               
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256                                                                                           
    Session-ID: 7424ED1C107C03074A5D03917D9E20DBDE47FEDCEE5082A4C8E578B72D8A4C4B                                                      
    Session-ID-ctx:                                                                                                                   
    Master-Key: 91637E390AE072301B462D1E18833BF397382935373755A77F62E72C209C2B219C36D21DA645BEBD2D369B70F16EC4B9                      
    Key-Arg   : None                                                                                                                  
    PSK identity: None                                                                                                                
    PSK identity hint: None                                                                                                           
    SRP username: None                                                                                                                
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 64800 (seconds)                                                                                 
    TLS session ticket:                                                                                                               
    0000 - cc b5 d7 9c 8b 78 b4 df-3a 0b 5f d7 bd 86 63 10   .....x..:._...c.                                                         
    0010 - 49 00 38 4d 47 91 a3 d9-95 db 5b 52 a7 94 45 df   I.8MG.....[R..E.                                                         
    0020 - f2 16 9f 00 98 ed f1 f3-60 f7 dc 76 01 d6 c1 85   ........`..v....                                                         
    0030 - b9 67 d2 7a 22 b3 31 16-34 6b 36 96 8d 32 cf 55   .g.z".1.4k6..2.U                                                         
    0040 - 30 b8 de 99 76 11 3c 2a-29 fa cc 97 a3 03 4a 11   0...v.<*).....J.                                                         
    0050 - 98 d4 b2 0b 40 7d 5a cf-5b 1d 66 10 df cd fb 4d   ....@}Z.[.f....M                                                         
    0060 - 37 ec bc 7e 2e 02 83 ac-3c fd e0 27 24 a5 99 ee   7..~....<..'$...                                                         
    0070 - ed 4a 7b 68 fb d8 5b 87-f7 fa ea fe fb 90 86 ca   .J{h..[.........                                                         
    0080 - dc 25 03 93 81 04 c8 f0-34 33 1e a4 42 54 5b 2d   .%......43..BT[-                                                         
    0090 - 1c 13 ef e7 ec 47 10 9a-cc 28 52 b2 92 ce 76 6a   .....G...(R...vj                                                         

    Start Time: 1423741379                                                                                                            
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)                                                                                                             
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)                                                                   
---                                                                                                                                   
closed
```

#### 追記

環境を記載していませんでしたので追記しておきます。
Windows 7 上でVagrantを使いUbuntu14.04をインストールしてその中での操作結果になります。

#### 追記2

`GlobalSign_Root_CA.crt`の有効期限を確認しましたが有効範囲でした。

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -dates -in /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GlobalSign_Root_CA.crt
notBefore=Sep  1 12:00:00 1998 GMT
notAfter=Jan 28 12:00:00 2028 GMT
```

Comment: `echo "" | openssl s_client -connect jp.globalsign.com:443 | openssl x509 -dates -noout` として、`notAfter` が期限の切れる日時です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。現在は有効期限内なのですが、だとしたら`wget`で取得できないのにはまた別の理由があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 質問欄で挙げられている記事を確認しましたが、wget を実行しているホストの `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` が期限切れなのではないでしょうか。こちらにある CentOS 6.6 では `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`  の有効期限が 2015/8/17 になっていて、wget でエラーは発生しません。

Comment: CentOSではなくUbuntuを使ってるので`ca-bundle.crt`と同等のファイルを探した所 `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` がそうだと http://askubuntu.com/questions/342484/etc-pki-tls-certs-ca-bundle-crt-not-found で述べられてたんですが、そのファイルには`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`と`-----END CERTIFICATE-----`で区切られた鍵そのものがあるだけで有効期限についての記述がありませんでした。ローカルのルート証明書の問題だということはわかりましたので他の方の回答を参考に鍵の置き換えを試してみます。

Comment: ところで、本題は「そのUbuntu環境からGlobalSignの証明書を使ったサイトにアクセスできない」という話で合っていたのでしょうか。もしその環境をサーバーとして使う場合の中間CA証明書のことが本題なのであれば、質問主さんがされたwgetを使っての実験は意味がないので…。

Comment: はい、あくまでUbuntuはクライアントとして使用しています。知りたいことは「SSLのエラーが発生した時の問題部分の特定方法」です。globalsignの証明書を使ってるサイトが一部のAndroid端末だと証明書のエラーになりiPhoneやPCではならなかったので原因を知りたく調べていたのですが自力では解決できず質問いたしました。

Comment: 「globalsignの証明書‌​を使ってるサイトが一部のAndroid端末だと証明書のエラーになりiPhoneやPCではならなかったので原因を知りたく」というところを真っ先に質問に書いてほしかったです・・・

Comment: すいません、Android端末で発生した問題がwgetでも発生したために同じ原因だと思い込んで、前提条件のずれた質問をしてしまいました。

Comment: @ironsand [お礼（bounty）](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)を開始されたようですが、まだ何か疑問点がありましたでしょうか？

Comment: 詳しく教えていただいたのでお礼に +50をしようとしたのですが、一定時間立たないと追加できないようです…。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

※2015/2/13：内容に誤りがあったため、また「[globalsignの証明書‌​を使ってるサイトが一部のAndroid端末だと証明書のエラーになりiPhoneやPCではならなかったので原因を知りたく調べていた](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/6385/8000#comment5362_6385)」とのことなので、回答を全面的に書き直しました。

### GlobalSignの証明書を使っているサイトが一部Android端末でエラーになる

具体的にどのサイトをどの端末で見たのか不明なので、考えられるケースを挙げることしかできませんが・・・

- SHA256の証明書が使われているが、端末がAndroid2.3未満（[Android2.3より対応](https://jp.globalsign.com/support/faq/540.html)）
- Android2.2で修正された脆弱性に由来する問題（https://jp.globalsign.com/support/faq/518.html）
- 端末に2014/1/28に有効期限を迎えたルート証明書しか入っていない
  （[非対応になった端末一覧](https://jp.globalsign.com/support/faq/537.html)）
- サイトがEV SSLを利用しているが、端末にR2のルート証明書が入っておらず、サーバー側でクロスルート証明書を用意していない or [2014/1/28に有効期限が切れた](https://jp.globalsign.com/information/important/2011/05/337.html)

といったところでしょうか。

### Ubuntu 14.04 で`jp.globalsign.com`に接続できない

Ubuntu14.04の環境を用意して試してみましたが、再現しませんでした。ただ、`/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R2.crt`を削除して`update-ca-certificates`すると全く同じエラーが表示されました。

一度上記ファイルが存在するかどうか確認してみていただけますか？存在しない場合は`apt-get install ca-certificates`で更新してみてください。

なおこれまでの回答で`GlobalSign_Root_CA.crt`について触れていましたが、これを削除しても上記のエラーは出ず、逆に存在していてもR2がなければエラーになっていました。ミスリードして申し訳ありません。

ただGlobalSignの場合、R2の証明書がない環境のために[クロスルート証明書が提供されているので](https://jp.globalsign.com/support/faq/431.html)、これがサーバー側に入っていれば`GlobalSign Root CA`だけでも検証できるはずなのですが・・・どうも`jp.globalsign.com`には入っていないように見えます。

Comment: Ubuntu14.04なら十分新しいし、そもそも`jp.globalsign.com`はevsslだからroot r2だし、参考記事とwgetのエラー違うし、別の問題のような気がしてきた…。

Comment: ありがとうございます。教えて頂いたコマンドで`GlobalSign_Root_CA.crt`の有効期限を確認して本文に追記しました。

Comment: @irons 追記内容やコメントでの補足を受けて全面的に書き直しました。再度ご確認いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 詳しい解説有難うございます。 ` /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/GlobalSign_Root_CA_-_R2.crt` は元から存在しており、念のため`apt-get install ca-certificates`を行った所 `ca-certificates is already the newest version.`で何もインストールされませんでした。ただ、この作業の直前にWindows及びUbuntuの再起動を行ったのですが、`wget`で`https://jp.globalsign.com` の取得ができるようになってしまっていました。しかし依然としてGlobalSignの証明書を使っているサイトではエラーになってしまいます。セキュリティの問題があるかもしれないので、できればそのURLは出さずにおきたいのですが…。

Comment: エラーになる、というのはAndroidでですよね？

Comment: いえ、Ubuntuの`wget`でです。

Comment: となると確かにサーバーの構成に問題があるかもしれません。[GlobalSignのSSLチェックツール](https://sslcheck.globalsign.com/ja/)などを使うと原因がわかるかもしれませんが、もし解決しないようであれば整理のために一度新しい質問を作成してはいかがでしょうか。その際「一部のAndroid端末でエラーが出るが、Ubuntu14.04のwgetでもエラーが出てしまう。ただしサーバーのURLは伏せておきたい」というあたりに触れていただくとよいかと思います。（質問する時点では各種コマンドの実行結果はなくても構いません）

Comment: こんなサイトがあるんですね！該当サイトを試したところ”サーバの設定に全ての中間CA証明書が含まれていません”と出ましたのでサーバー側の構成だと判断できました。今回は大変勉強になりましたありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

メッセージを見る限り、中間CA証明書の検証でエラーが出ているようです。英語の翻訳に自信がないですが、ルート証明書が古いかない場合のエラーのようです。（もしかしたら、中間CA証明書がない場合のエラーかもしれませんが。）
　[ここ](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#HTTPS-_0028SSL_002fTLS_0029-Options)の--ca-certificateオプションの説明によると、wgetはシステムの証明書を使うようなので、そこに足りない証明書を追加する（例えば、Ubuntuなら[この辺り](https://mistymagich.wordpress.com/2012/01/17/ubuntu%E3%81%AB%E8%87%AA%E5%B7%B1%E8%AA%8D%E8%A8%BC%E5%B1%80%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%BC%E6%98%8E%E6%9B%B8%E3%82%92%E7%99%BB%E9%8C%B2/)を参照）か、前記オプションなどで別途取得した足りない証明書を指定する必要があると思います。
　なお、同様なエラーが出る環境が手元にないため、上記方法でうまくいくかは未確認です。

また、エラーがでた証明書を調べたり取得する方法は、Firefoxでは以下の通りです。

1. https://jp.globalsign.com/ にアクセスします。
2. 右クリックし、「ページの情報を表示」を選択します。
3. 「セキュリティ」を選択し、「証明書を表示」をクリックします。
4. 「詳細」を選択すると、証明書の階層が表示されるので、選択すると詳細が分かります。
5. 「エクスポート」をクリックすると、選択した証明書がエクスポートされます。